# Install Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Windows8 machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, installation

I was trying to install Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Windows 8 PC. In some final stage I got message

This driver cannot be used due compatibility issues

```
VSPerf Profiling Control Driver
Microsoft Corporation
```

Later, when system was trying to install SQL Server Express I got final result:

```
The following component failed to install:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Services Pack 1 (x64)
```

I was trying to run VS and got message:

```
Cannot create the window.
```

How to solve these problems and make visual studio running on Windows8?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but the profiling driver cannot be used in Windows 8: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8.aspx